# Django Crispy Form filter by is_staff

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I have a form to upload article posts but how would I filter the author so it just shows users who have the is_staff role, I also need it to show authors as usernames rather than email adresses

Here is my forms.py

```py
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = TagField(required=False, widget=LabelWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('article_name', 'author', 'content', 'tags', 'status')
```

Here is my views.py

```py
class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name = 'main_website/new_article.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html   

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        articles = Article.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-date_posted')[:2]
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = articles
        context['title'] = 'New Article'
        return context
```

Here is my models.py

```py
class Article(models.Model):

    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        Draft = 0
        Published = 1

    article_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='news_updates')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status.choices, default=Status.Draft, help_text=_('Decide whether you want to Publish the news article or save it as a Draft'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("main_website_article_detail", args=[str(self.slug)])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.article_name)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = TagField(required=False, widget=LabelWidget)
    author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True))

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('article_name', 'author', 'content', 'tags', 'status')
```

And for your second question (taken from django docs):

> The **str**() method of the model will be called to generate string
> representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices. To
> provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and
> override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object
> and should return a string suitable for representing it. For example:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "My Object #%i" % obj.id
```